# Microsoft Excel - Is there any way to split rows in multiple columns by a certain number of rows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

So for example I'm working with data that pertains various information for customers throughout columns containing various bits about them. 

`Name  |  email|  Phone
Guy     l@d.com  50230`

And continues with 1,000's of customers. 
Now I need to break the rows into groups of 400 and allocate them onto new spreadsheets so I can upload them to a texting software so I can send updates and other campaigns.

Is there any efficient way to go about this? Usually I do it manually and scroll down until I hit 400 and then I select the rest of the columns. But that tends to be fairly time consuming. So any advice?

Comment: So you mean, copy every group of 400 rows and put them in a new spreadsheet?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's already a distinct group of 400, marked by something like an empty space, I think it's hard to find a built in function for this specific task.
However, you could make your own using macros.

So if I understand your example correctly, you select on cell, then go down 400 rows, and select them all, plus two more columns. The easiest way to do that in a macro should be this:

```vb
Sub select400()
selection.Resize(400, 3).Select
End Sub
```

Then you can assignt a shortcut to this macro, by going to the macro window and options, or with the help of another macro.

But what if you don't want a set amount of rows or columns?
Then you could replace the absolute values with input boxes and variables, something like this:

```vb
Sub select400()
Dim inpRows As Long, inpColumns As Long
inpRows = InputBox("How many rows to select?")
inpColumns = InputBox("How many columns to select?")
selection.Resize(inpRows, inpColumns).Select
End Sub
```

Although since that has InputBox, it should have a proper error handling. It will crash if anything odd (or nothing at all) is written in the boxes.

Sample:

[image]

I also ran this first:

```vb
Sub setShortcut()
Application.OnKey "%{s}", "select400"
End Sub
```

To set my macro to run when I press ALT + s

You can ofc further extend the automatisation by having the macro find 400, cut into a new worksheet/workbook, and then keep going with new sheets until you run out of data.

It's a bit more technical, but can be done with a loop or two.